# GIT HTTPS connection issue

Tags: git, ssl, curl, libcurl, opensuse

I searched around on stackoverflow and I haven't found anything that exactly answers this question so I wanted to ask it here and provide as much detail as possible about my problem.

I just installed openSUSE 12.3, installed git and tried to clone into one of my repos using https.  This following command works on Ubuntu, Mac and other operating systems without issue but for some reason I am having trouble on SUSE.

When I run:

```
git clone https://username@mysite.com/git/myrepo.git
```

It hangs when "Cloning into 'myrepo'

I have already disabled sslverify and this is how it works on other machines.  I don't believe this is an sslverify issue because when I don't have sslverify on other machines I get a specific error message regarding that.  In this case I just get a hang on 'Cloning into ...'

I ran the following command to get more info:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://username@mysite.com/git/myrepo.git
```

The output from that is:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
* Couldn't find host mysite.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to mysite.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connected to mysite.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* Connected to mysite.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to mysite.com:443 
* Closing connection #0
error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to mysite.com:443  while accessing https://username@mysite.com/git/myrepo.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I obviously changed the username, IP and DNS name for the sake of this question.

I have heard older versions of curl had issues but this version is one of the newer ones.  The version of libcurl on Ubuntu is actually older so I still don't think this is a bug but not totally sure.  I don't have the privilege of changing this from HTTPS to SSH so that is not an alternative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a follow up, I am able to clone into repos that have a valid certificate.  For example, I cloned a github repo via https and it works fine.  I should add that the repo I am cloning into that fails has a self-signed certificate.  Disabling SSL Verify does the trick on other machines but does not work on SUSE.

Comment: I also am using gitblit on the server, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is rather the SSL library (version) and not particularly the libcurl version. It looks like you might be using OpenSSL so compare the versions of the working vs the non-working ones in that aspect...

Comment: The OpenSSL version on the SUSE machine is 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013.  I checked on the ubuntu machine and it was 1.0.1 14 March 2012.  So the SUSE version is indeed newer.